# Nibbana or the Kingdom?

Tags: comparative-religion

Several years ago, One of my mates gave a book - 'Nibbana (Nirvana) or the Kingom'. I am trying to check any other recent prints. The last print was in 1964. Were there any rewrites?

Can someone give a synopsis?

Comment: "Also, is there any commonly quoted verse by Buddha/Mahayana studies on the root cause of Suffering?" - Is this in reference to the same book? If not, you should create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1964 edition of that book (by Egerton Baptist) is the most recent edition.

Answer (score 0):

Published in 1964, the author, a Christian-turned-Buddhist, compares the proverbial Christian adage “kingdom of god” to the Buddhist Brahma heaven.  He also claims that Jesus was not completely enlightened, perhaps more like a bodhisattva, and who upon being reborn (2nd coming) could achieve full buddhahood.  For the author, statement such as, “to be one with my father” is proof that Jesus’ trajectory is the Brahma realm, not nibbana.  He references Mahāgovindasutta (The Great Steward) Sutta in which, in a past life, Buddha taught the path that leads to rebirth in the Brahma realm.  After the centaur recites Buddha's past life story, Buddha’s reply is:

> “I remember, Pañcasikha. I myself was the brahmin Great Steward at
> that time.  And I taught those disciples the path to rebirth in the
> company of Brahmā. But that spiritual path of mine doesn’t lead to
> disillusionment, dispassion, cessation, peace, insight, awakening, and
> extinguishment. It only leads as far as rebirth in the Brahmā realm.
>
> But this spiritual path does lead to disillusionment, dispassion,
> cessation, peace, insight, awakening, and extinguishment. And what is
> the spiritual path that leads to extinguishment? It is simply this
> noble eightfold path, that is: right view, right thought, right
> speech, right action, right livelihood, right effort, right
> mindfulness, and right immersion. This is the spiritual path that
> leads to disillusionment, dispassion, cessation, peace, insight,
> awakening, and extinguishment.

The author also claims other gnostic teachings of Jesus such as karma and rebirth.

Comment: Brahma is not the Almighty... Even Brahma's enlightenment is incomplete. Truth is bitter. Isn't Nibbana laziness? Bliss all the time? while other's bicycle Ha? A true yogi never rests...Ask Brahma..He knows what it takes to make something. The level of effort. The comprehension requirement.  You think Nibbana is free :-)  blue_ego ? . Think again.